# Passing reference of global object in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to implement a global object which stores every parameter that I can pass between pages. My object is called AppObject. I can declare it in my mainpage.xaml.cs and then pass it through reference using

```
Page.Navigate(typeof(anotherpage), AppObject);
```

However, I would like to save the objects to file through the on_suspending event. How can I pass this parameter to the on_suspending event or is there anyway for me to declare this AppObject in the app.xaml.cs and then pass it to the mainpage.xaml.cs?

My App.xaml.cs

```
AppObject AppObject = new AppObject();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }

...more code

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
    /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
    /// of memory still intact.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
    private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();

        // TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity

        //I want to write to file here and be able to refereence to the AppObject which I pass around.

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

Comment: You can declare `public AppObject yourObj = new AppObject();` in *App.xaml.cs* and then access it from the whole app like this: `(App.Current as App).yourObj`. Note also that passing non value types as navigation parameter is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks! Using (App.Current as App).yourObj works! May I ask what's the downfall of this method as you mentioned?

Comment: Navigating with parameter works along with suspension manager, if your parameter is not serializable then you will get an exception. But hence you have your object app wide, then maybe there is no need to pass it as parameter. Also you should handle this carefully, especially once the app is suspended/resumed/terminated by OS - ensure that your object was loaded correctly upon resuming.

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml.cs, make sure the objects you need are public. Say you have something like this:

```
public AppObject appObject = new AppObject();
```

Now, in MainPage.xaml.cs, you just have to create the objects of the same type you want to pass. Then, create another object that has the reference to the App like this:

```
var appReference = App.Current as App;
AppObject objectInMain = appReference.appObject;
```

Now you have another object in MainPage.xaml.cs, that is the exact copy of the one in App.xaml.cs. You've just effectively passed data between two pages. You can create a reference to the App in any page as shown above and use the variables declared in App.xaml.cs in that page.